# How to return a value instead of a status if request is not authorised?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, jwt

```
[authorise]
public string Get()
{
    return "value1";
}
```

if I am not **authorised** it will return a status of **401 not authorised**.

can it return a value such as json "`{status:false,code:"401"}`". ?

Comment: You still need to return a status code.

Comment: @Haytam that means It can not auto return the code right?which means I can not use [authorize]

Comment: If you use |Authorize], and if the user isn't authenticated, the code is always 401.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use custommiddleware to achieve your requirement.

You could captured the 401 error in middleware and then rewrite the response body to `{status:false,code:"401"}`

More details, you could add below codes into Configure method above the `app.UseAuthentication();`:

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 401)
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("{status:false,code:'401'}");
            }
        });
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> can it return a value such as json "`{status:false,code:"401"}`". ?

Sure, you can.

```
[ApiController]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
        { 
            return new OkObjectResult(new { status: true, code: 200 });
        }
        return new OkObjectResult(new { status: false, code: 401 });
    }
}
```

But notice that, the request will return with the *real* status code 200 (`OK`)

---

You can also use `UnauthorizedObjectResult` like @vivek's comment:

```
return new UnauthorizedObjectResult(new { status: false, code: 401 });
```

Comment: You can also use `JsonResult` if you want more customization, like the status code.

Comment: It should return UnauthorizedObjectResult

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom authorize attribute using `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter`.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public AuthorizationPolicy Policy { get; }

    public CustomAuthorizeFilter(AuthorizationPolicy policy)
    {
        Policy = policy ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(policy));
    }

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        // Allow Anonymous skips all authorization
        if (context.Filters.Any(item =&amp;gt; item is IAllowAnonymousFilter))
        {
            return;
        }

        var policyEvaluator = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService&amp;lt;IPolicyEvaluator&amp;gt;();
        var authenticateResult = await policyEvaluator.AuthenticateAsync(Policy, context.HttpContext);
        var authorizeResult = await policyEvaluator.AuthorizeAsync(Policy, authenticateResult, context.HttpContext, context);

        if (authorizeResult.Challenged)
        {
            // Return custom 401 result
            context.Result = new CustomUnauthorizedResult("Authorization failed.");
        }
        else if (authorizeResult.Forbidden)
        {
            // Return default 403 result
            context.Result = new ForbidResult(Policy.AuthenticationSchemes.ToArray());
        }
    }
}

public class CustomUnauthorizedResult : JsonResult
{
    public CustomUnauthorizedResult(string message)
        : base(new CustomError(message))
    {
        StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
    }
}

public class CustomError
{
    public string Error { get; }

    public CustomError(string message)
    {
        Error = message;
    }
}
```

The code in this article does exactly what you want. [click here](https://ignas.me/tech/custom-unauthorized-response-body/)

Answer (score 0):

You can return the below if using Asp.Net Core 3.1, It returns `UnauthorizedObjectResult`.

```
return Unauthorized(new { status: false, code: 401 });
```

Comment: {status=false,code=401},sorry I write the wrong code

Comment: no,I want to it auto return if I tag it with [Authorize].But it seems can not be.

Comment: Then you can sue the custom attribute

Comment: how to custom it?